# Formatar valor do Real (br) para decimal(10,2) do mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde, galera!
Como formatar valor do Real (br) para numeric(10,2) do mysql usando o number_format do php?

Tentei usar:

```
$num="89,90"; ou $num="1.089,90";
number_format($num, 2, '.', '');
```

Mas esta zerando os centavos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php) do php requer que o primeiro parâmetro (o `$_POST['valor']` no seu caso) seja um float.

> string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals ] )

Então, se a sua entrada for `20,05` isso não será considerado float e será convertido de forma errada mesmo. Com o seguinte erro:

**Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered**

Você pode fazer isso:

```
number_format(str_replace(",",".",str_replace(".","","1.089,90")), 2, '.', '');
```

Desta forma você garante que será entregue no formato correto.

É interessante reparar que a função `number_format` faz um cast deste valor para float. E se você fizer a mesma coisa:

```
var_dump((float)"20,05");
```

Verá que o resultado será:

```
float(20)
```

E não `20.05` como esperado.

Comment: Boa tarde, Andrei!
$_POST['valor'] é uma string, um input text
funcionou para o valor 89,90 mas não para 1.089,90

Comment: @MárcioTeixeira deu certo?

Comment: @MárcioTeixeira tente agora.

Comment: Funcionou, perfeito!

Answer (score 3):

Gosto de fazer assim;

Esse primeiro método remove todos os caracteres especiais da sua string.

```
/**
 * @param $str
 *
 * @return null|string|string[]
 */
public static function onlyNumbers($str)
{
    $str = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Esse segundo, recebe uma strnig, e retorna o valor em decimal para uso no banco de dados. Eu geralmente coloco isso num helper, ou algo do tipo.

```
/**
 * @param $str
 * @return string
 */
public static function formatMoneyDb($str)
{
    $str = number_format((self::onlyNumbers($str) / 100), 2);
    $str = str_replace(',', '', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

É bem simples, vamos declarar uma variável de exemplo.

```
$num = 100000.50;
```

O padrão no formato americano USD.

```
number_format($num, 2); // $100,000.50
```

O nosso padrão BRL

```
number_format($num, 2, ',', '.'); // R$100.000,50
```

Comment: Valeu Guilherme, mas eu preciso de exatamente o contrário.
$num = 89,90 para 89.9

Answer (score 2):

Considerando que o *MySQL/MariaDB* esperam um valor do tipo *float* para colunas tipo `decimal()`, deve-se formatar seu número antes de inserir no db.

Respeitando isto, fiz essa função (estruturado):

```
function brl2decimal($brl, $casasDecimais = 2) {
    // Se já estiver no formato USD, retorna como float e formatado
    if(preg_match('/^\d+\.{1}\d+$/', $brl))
        return (float) number_format($brl, $casasDecimais, '.', '');
    // Tira tudo que não for número, ponto ou vírgula
    $brl = preg_replace('/[^\d\.\,]+/', '', $brl);
    // Tira o ponto
    $decimal = str_replace('.', '', $brl);
    // Troca a vírgula por ponto
    $decimal = str_replace(',', '.', $decimal);
    return (float) number_format($decimal, $casasDecimais, '.', '');
}

var_dump(brl2decimal('150.99', 2)); // float(150.99)
var_dump(brl2decimal('10.123456789', 3)); // float(10.123)
var_dump(brl2decimal('R$ 10,99', 2)); // float(10.99)
var_dump(brl2decimal('89,999', 3)); // float(89.999)
var_dump(brl2decimal('1.089,90')); // float(1089.9)
var_dump(brl2decimal('1.089,99')); // float(1089.99)
```

E fiz também uma classe (oo): [GitHub/lipespry - Classe Moeda](https://github.com/lipespry/moeda-php-classe)

Inserindo no banco de dados com coluna tipo `decimal(10, 2)`:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `decimal` VALUES (10.99), (89.999), (1089.9), (1089.99);
Query OK, 4 rows affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> SELECT * FROM `decimal`;
+---------+
| valor   |
+---------+
|   10.99 |
|   90.00 |
| 1089.90 |
| 1089.99 |
+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**@edit:** Função aprimorada: se já estiver no formato USD, retorna como float e formatado
**@edit2:** Adicionado link para classe no *GitHub*.

Comment: É uma função "bala de prata" muito boa!

Comment: Pensando bem, esqueci de uma coisa! Vou editar. kk